MariaDB general query log - ID meaning
I use MariaDB and I needed general query log for debugging my app DB statements. I wonder what ID column actually means? Is it connection ID?

The documentation tells nothing about id column... and quering does not show such column too.

In MariaDB the general query log records information about SQL statements received from clients along with connection and disconnection events. The ID column refers to the thread ID. Each connection to the MariaDB server is assigned a unique ID. The ID column doesn't directly map to a connection ID, however since each connection spawns a separate thread for query execution, the thread ID effectively acts as an indirect connection identifier.

Unravel the log by id to look at individual connections; keep the log intact to see interactions.
